# Unity Ads Xcode 6.3.1 setUnityVersion crash

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, addition

I'm using the last version of UnityAds 1.1.4 with Unity 4.6.4f1. I have upgraded to Xcode 6.3.1 and I can build IOS version but when I'm running the game on the device I get the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UnityAds setUnityVersion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c19f6d0' 

This appears in UnityAdsUnityWrapper.m at line : [[UnityAds sharedInstance] setUnityVersion:unityVersion];
```

Everything was working before Xcode update and Unityads update

Comment: try to post your code where you have the adds, etc. will help you to get answers

Answer (score 0):

Unity Ads dev here. This is probably caused by a problem when upgrading the asset store package. You should remove all Unity Ads related files from your Unity project and reimport the package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this worked for me:

1. Search project with 'UnityAds' and delete every asset that is found
2. Delete Plugins/iOS/DeviceInfo.framework
3. Delete Editor/PostprocessBuildPlayer_DeviceInfo
4. Re-import newest version of UnityAds

I'm using XCode 6.3.1 & Unity 4.6.3f1